# How to make some base code for App class?

Tags: c#, wpf, base-class

For example, I create WPF application and want to add some logic that I use at each my application - like logging, unhandled exception handling, etc. I use code like this (it doesn't matter what it actually does - just code that does something) in my example WPF application:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException 
            += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionHandler);

        ServiceInjector.InjectServices();

        base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.Show();
    }

    void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        var exceptionObj = args.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        if (exceptionObj == null)
            exceptionObj = new NotSupportedException(
                "Unhandled exception doesn't derive from System.Exception: " 
                + args.ExceptionObject.ToString());

        // TODO: Logging...

        var messageBox = GetService<IMessageBoxService>();
        messageBox.Show(
            exceptionObj.Message, 
            "Unhandled exception.",
            MessageBoxButton.OK,
            MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

        Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    #region Resolve service dependencies members.

    public TServiceContract GetService<TServiceContract>()
        where TServiceContract : class
    {
        return ServiceContainer.Instance.GetService<TServiceContract>();
    }

    #endregion Resolve service dependencies members.
}
```

I want to use some code inside OnStartup (UnhandledException subscribing, injecting services), UnhandledExceptionHandler itself and GetService method in all my WPF applications without copy-pasting it by hands. What is the best way?

I have read a little about base class for App (derived from Application), but it seems that it has many drawbacks like problems with App.g.i.cs file (part of App class declaration), with XAML support (need to have App.xaml because Fluent's components don't want to work without adding reference to it through ResourceDictionary inside App.xaml), etc.

Comment: Reinventing wheels always make very painful corners on result :) After you are done learning how to work with try/catch and writng to file, for cross-cutting concerns you've mentioned consider using existing libraries which usually come with existing recommended way of wiring up into many types of applications.

Comment: While I do agree with @AlexeiLevenkov, sometimes it's good for your learning curve to do things the hard way first, as you then not only learn to appreciate why there's easier ways, but you also gain a deeper understanding of why and how such common libraries work.

Comment: I don't understand what are you meaning in my case. I already use common libraries - NLog for logging, for example. The point of my question is laid on another area: I have a common code - how I can bring it in every new my application with minimum adaptations to application type and with minimum efforts? In simple case I can use a base class. But in case of WPF app it is not so simple - the standard "WPF application" template creates partial App class and some set of predefined settings - so I have to recreate it in my base class and another dificulties. And I ask can I escape it and how.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to re-use code across projects (and especially across project types: wpf, winforms, console, web, etc), you might want to look into creating a separate class library project.  These types of projects don't have a user interface/application: they are instead compiled to DLL files, which you can then reference in other .NET projects as you see fit.

Alternatively, within the same solution you can have multiple projects.  It's not uncommon to have a number of projects with dependencies set up between them such that two different application projects within the same solution both use yet another class library project for a shared code base.

See below:

[image]

This is a typical web application project template that I use.  The Domain project is at the bottom of the dependency chain, consisting of business objects that all other projects reference.  The Data project contains data access code that other projects can access (except Domain).  Web is the web application, and Services is a console application for server based utilities, etc.  They both share the same Domain and Data (and a few other) projects.

In the case of the above, in my Web project I'd set a reference to the DomainServices project, then do something like this in my Web project:

```
using System;
using Template.DomainServices;
namespace Template.Web {
    public class MyClass {
        ILogger logger = new DomainServices.DefaultLogger();
        public void Log(string msg) {
            logger.Log(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

We're now using the logger implementation from the DomainServices shared project, calling it from the Web project, and we could do the same with any other project we wanted as well (granted, this is hardly the most technically-correct in terms of the code shown, but you get the idea?)

Perhaps that gives some ideas on how this can be approached?

One complication with deriving from the WPF base classes (or any application platform specific classes) is that your library classes are now tied to that particular application platform.  In some cases this may be desireable, if the required functionality is specific to that platform.  In other cases, such as loggers and such (and a great many other things), they can be just plain old C# objects (POCOs) that can be consumed by any application platform.  The goal is typically to write platform-agnostic libraries except when there's specific need to target or extend a specific platform.

Comment: I will be more specific: I have UnhandledException handler that contains logging - how can I use such a handler through all akin apps - WPF, Forms, UWP? Base class, dependency injection, custom Visual Studio's template for each type of app, or whatever?

Comment: And more unspecific: I have code that handles unhandled exception (in one way for all apps' types), injects services or whatever - I want to add this code in all new apps in startup. Is there a way to do it in uniform way or it requires individual approach for WPF, Forms, UWP, WCF apps?

Comment: I already know that I can use external libraries as services and so on. But how to add services injection, UnhandledException event subscription and some other basic initialization code in all types of apps uniformly? Maybe it is not possible (or just is not the best way?) and it is worth to create custom startup template for each type of application, in which I add such initialization in a manner specific for each type of application?

Comment: Each application entry point (or somewhere in the entry chain) will have it's own DI/IoC setup.  You can't generalize _everything_ - some things still need to be done per-platform.

Comment: jdl134679, I investigated this question and decided to use some base custom project template per platform. I create app with default template, add my code where it needs to me, and then save this project with base initialization as a new template. Base class approach seems to be more specific and complicated if it is used with default templates - default templates already contains some inner initialization logic, some settings through the project and some other things that I need to recreate in my base custom class. So it seems easier to extend a default teplate with my code.

Comment: T4 templates are a good way to standardize boilerplate project setups and code, but that's not quite the same thing as base classes/inheritance and general OOP practice.  They're two different things, although they can mix a bit... in any case, a pinch of that here, a sprinkle of this there and ultimately it all has the potential to come together nicely when balanced correctly.  Have fun!